# Refer to cell on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

This seems like something I should be able to figure out, however, I am struggling with this.

I try to set the range to a variable to then refer to that range in an equation. The variable though takes the current value of the cell. You may recognize this from yesterday. I had gotten it working, but someone said I should be referring to the variable as a range and that is where I am having the issue.

```
    Dim Sacc, GSacc As Range

   'I want this to refer to the range, that is happening is Sacc = "Test Cell"
    Set Sacc = Sheets(2).Range("F4")

    Sacc.Select 'this works

    'run-time error 1004
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Formula = "=IF('" & Sacc & " = """",""LMonth not done"",""LMonth Done"")"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you need to reference the address of the cell. You don't need to select the cell first, and you should add the variable type after each declaration. In your code `Sacc` is declared as a `variant`.

```
Sub x()

Dim Sacc As Range, GSacc As Range

Set Sacc = Sheets(2).Range("F4")

Sacc.Offset(1).Formula = "=IF(" & Sacc.Address & " = """",""LMonth not done"",""LMonth Done"")"

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting the same error when referring to it as Sacc.Address

Comment: Works for me. Picture added.

Comment: My pleasure. Could you start accepting some answers please?

Comment: Sorry! I am not very active and didn't know about that.

Comment: That's ok, thanks. When you get time perhaps you can look over your previous questions too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use R1C1 notation and simplify your code

and you don't want to select anything

as follows.

```
Sheets(2).Range("F5").Formula = "=IF(R[-1]C = """",""LMonth not done"",""LMonth Done"")"
```

you can also use `ISBLANK()` excel function to test for empty cells:

```
Sheets(2).Range("F4").Offset(1).Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(R[-1]C),""LMonth not done"",""LMonth Done"")"
```

Comment: The reason I changed it from R1C1 is that I don't really understand how that works. Thank you for the ISBLANK() tip!